# Combining/merging multiple columns unique values in a single row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, grouping, ssms, aggregate-functions

Trying to combine multiple columns and rows with a single query in SSMS. Here is a simpler version of more complex table I am working with:

Here is my current query:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
([C1] varchar(50), [C2] varchar(50), [C3] varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
([C1], [C2], [C3])
VALUES
('F92', 'Game1', 'b100'),
('F92', 'Game1', 'b200'),
('F92', 'Game2', 'C200'),
('F92', 'Game2', 'D400')
;



SELECT
 C1,C2,
 STUFF(
     (SELECT ', ' + C3
      FROM Table1
      WHERE C1 = a.C1 AND C2 = a.C2
      FOR XML PATH (''))
      , 1, 1, '')  AS NamesList
FROM Table1 AS a
GROUP BY C1,C2

drop table table1
```

I intend to get result as:

```
C1   | Namelist
F92  | Game1 b100, b200 Game2 c200, d400
```

is this doable in a single query?

Comment: What a great job posting ddl, sample data and desired output. It really makes it easy to help when you put in the effort to post that much information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do this. You can use a cte to get the delimited list you are already getting. Then take the results and turn that into another delimited list. But you might want something as a delimiter between groups other than a space.

```
with FirstPass as
(
    SELECT
     C1,
     C2 + ' ' + STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + C3
          FROM Table1
          WHERE C1 = a.C1 AND C2 = a.C2
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS NamesList
    FROM Table1 AS a
    GROUP BY C1,C2
)

select C1
    , NameList = stuff((select ' ' + fp2.NamesList
        from FirstPass fp2
        where fp.C1 = fp2.C1
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
from FirstPass fp
group by fp.C1
```

Returns:

> F92   | Game1  b100, b200 Game2  C200, D400

--EDIT--

With the new requirements of needing to sort C2 by the count you can simply add a little aggregation. This is not much of a change from the original.

```
with FirstPass as
(
    SELECT
     C1,
     C2 + ' ' + STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + C3
          FROM Table1
          WHERE C1 = a.C1 AND C2 = a.C2
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS NamesList
    , count(*) as GameCount
    FROM Table1 AS a
    GROUP BY C1,C2
)

select distinct C1
    , NameList = stuff((select ' ' + fp2.NamesList
        from FirstPass fp2
        where fp.C1 = fp2.C1
        group by fp2.GameCount, fp2.NamesList
        order by fp2.GameCount desc
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
from FirstPass fp
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm. So here's another point I am stuck in (dont know if I should create a new ticket).

Comment: If this works you should consider marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Say the values now are

```
 VALUES
('F92', 'Game1', 'b100'),
('F92', 'Game1', 'b200'),
('F92', 'Game2', 'C200'),
('F92', 'Game2', 'D400'),
('F92', 'Game2', 'D500')
;
```

So now Game2 appears 3 times. Using Sean Lange's code result was organized in ascending order hence Game1 shows up before Game2. Is there a way to show result based on the count of column c2 (descending) so intended result would be

```
F92 | Game2 C200, D400, D500 Game1 b100, b200
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on this example. Here is the new query:

```
            CREATE TABLE Table1
            ([C1] varchar(50), [C2] varchar(50), [C3] varchar(50),[C4] varchar(50),[C5] varchar(50) )
            ;

            INSERT INTO Table1
            ([C1], [C2], [C3], [C4], [C5])
            VALUES
            ('F92', 'XBOX','81-94','Game1', 'B350'),
            ('F92', 'XBOX','81-94','Game1', 'B150'),
            ('F92', 'XBOX','76-80','Game2', 'PB100'),
            ('F92', 'XBOX','76-80','Game2', 'PB200'),
            ('F92', 'XBOX','95-97','Game2', 'PB300')
            ;

            with FirstPass as
            (
                SELECT
                 C1, c2, 
                    c3 + ' ' + c4+ + STUFF(
                     (SELECT ', ' +''+ c5
                      FROM Table1
                      WHERE C1 = a.C1 AND C2 = a.C2  AND C3 = a.C3  AND C4 = a.C4  
                      FOR XML PATH (''))
                      , 1, 1, '')  AS NamesList
                , count(*) as GameCount
                FROM Table1 AS a
                GROUP BY C1,C2,c3, c4
            )

            select distinct C1,C2
                , NameList = stuff((select ' ' + fp2.NamesList
                    from FirstPass fp2
                    where fp.C1 = fp2.C1
                    group by fp2.GameCount, fp2.NamesList
                    order by fp2.GameCount
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
                    into table2
            from FirstPass fp

            -- concatenate and insert into existing table

            insert into table2 (C1, conc)
            select C1, C2 + ' ' + NameList
            from FirstPass fp

            SELECT *  FROM table2


            drop table table1
            drop table table2
```

Desired result:

```
C1  |conc
F92 |XBOX 95-97 GAME2 PB300 76-80 GAME2 PB100, PB200 81-94 GAME1 B350, B150
```

and inserting this result into existing table "table2"

Is concatenating the best solution here achieve the desired result? This part of the query is throwing me off:

```
-- concatenate and insert into existing table

            insert into table2 (C1, conc)
            select C1, C2 + ' ' + NameList
            from FirstPass fp
```